# Building v8 on OSX

Tags: macos, v8

Following [this guid](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Getting%20Started%20with%20Embedding) I tried building V8 on OSX El Capitan (10.11.2).
At step 1 I run the following:

```
make x64.release -j 4
```

Which seems to succeed fine. Then I copy the code and; coming to step 3 I get the following error:

```
 v8 git:(4.8) ✗ g++ -I. hello_world.cpp -o hello_world -Wl,--start-group out/x64.release/obj.target/{tools/gyp/libv8_{base,libbase,external_snapshot,libplatform},third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n,data}}.a -Wl,--end-group -lrt -ldl -pthread -std=c++0x
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_libbase.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_external_snapshot.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_libplatform.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'out/x64.release/obj.target/third_party/icu/libicuuc.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'out/x64.release/obj.target/third_party/icu/libicui18n.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'out/x64.release/obj.target/third_party/icu/libicudata.a'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: shameless self promotion:  https://github.com/xaxxon/v8toolkit/blob/master/README.md  guide for using my library, but it starts with instructions for how to build current v8 on el capitan.   I did just that yesterday.

Comment: but your problem might be simpler -- you not setting your library directories properly and those aren't the locations of the library files for os x.   It's weird, but in os x the files are put direction into $V8_DIR/out/$BUILD/ instead of all that third-party stuff.   like /home/myusername/v8/out/native is where the .a files are for os x